# Create markov chains by reading multiples lines at once

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, bayesian, markov-chains

I want to generate a `Markov Chain` from the given data.

What I am trying to solve is if the first string of `PG` is `M vs. S type`. Well, its obvious that the string `A-G-T-T-C-A-G-T-G-T-A` is `M type` (on general observation) but I want to prepare a markov model to test this problem.

Rather than providing the `transition probability matrix for M vs. S` directly, I have to compute is on the go. So, I have to make the `markov chain` for each observed sequence for all the columns (by blocks).

**Problem 1:** Unlike in most cases where chains are generated based on same line of the text I have to generate the `MC` based on two different lines of the text.

```
block    PG    M1  M2  M3  M4  S1  S2  S3  S4
15       A|T   A   A   C   G   T   T   C   T
15       G|C   G   G   G   C   C   C   G   A
15       T|A   T   C   T   T   A   A   C   A
15       T|C   T   T   T   A   C   C   G   C
15       C|G   C   A   C   A   G   G   T   G
15       A|C   A   A   A   C   C   C   G   C
15       G|T   G   C   G   C   T   T   G   T
17       T|G   T   T   A   T   G   C   G   C
17       G|A   G   G   G   C   A   A   A   C
17       T|C   C   T   T   C   C   C   G   T
17       A|T   A   A   A   C   T   T   T   A
```

Lets say I want to create a `first order markov chain` to solve if the first string of `PG` is of `M type vs. S type`.

I prepare my `first order markov chain` as:

```
Note: the opening states and closing states in each chain are repeated it self.


block    PG        M1    M2    M3    M4    S1    S2    S3    S4
15       AgA|TgT   AgA   AgA   CgC   GgG   TgT   TgT   CgC   TgT # opening state (repeated itself)
15       GgA|CgT   GgA   GgA   GgC   CgG   CgT   CgT   GgC   AgT
15       TgG|AgC   TgG   CgG   TgG   TgC   AgC   AgC   CgG   AgA
15       TgT|CgA   TgT   TgC   TgT   AgT   CgA   CgA   GgC   CgA
15       CgT|GgC   CgT   AgT   CgT   AgA   GgC   GgC   TgG   GgC
15       AgC|CgG   AgC   AgA   AgC   CgA   CgG   CgG   GgT   CgG
15       GgA|TgC   GgA   CgA   GgA   CgC   TgC   TgC   GgG   TgC
15       GgG|TgT   GgG   CgC   GgG   CgC   TgT   TgT   GgG   TgT
# this last one was closing state so repeating the transition for it's own state

# new opening transition state for another block 17
17       TgT|GgG   TgT   TgT   AgA   TgT   GgT   CgC   GgG   CgC
17       GgT|AgG   GgT   GgT   GgA   CgT   AgG   AgC   AgG   CgC
17       TgG|CgA   CgG   TgG   TgG   CgC   CgA   CgA   GgA   TgC
17       AgT|TgC   AgC   AgT   AgT   CgC   TgC   TgC   TgG   AgT
17       AgA|TgT   AgA   AgA   AgA   CgC   TgT   TgT   TgT   AgA
# the last line is closing state for another block 17
```

**Problem 02:** But, if I want `second state markov chain`, I repeat the opening and closing state as it was, but now instead of preparing the chains from adjacent lines I prepare other `MC` using line 1 with line 3, line 2 with line 4, line 3 with line 5.. so on.

I tried to use several markov modules presented here https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=markov but looks like none are useful for what I am trying to do (or possibly I can't figure out). I think its just easy to prepare my own function.

Can any one share some thoughts or help on how to proceed about this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t looked enough into the libraries to be sure that one of those wouldn’t be more helpful, but the second state doesn’t need to deal with the awkwardness of looking multiple lines down.

Once you have first-order Markov Chains, *adjacent lines in that table tell you about 3 lines of information in the original matrix*.  All you need to do is parse that with a similar set of for loops.

For instance, looking at the first 3 rows of the “PG” column of the first-order, we get:

```
AgA
GgA
TgG
```

The first two rows tell you that `AgA` is a start row that started with `A`, and that the second row was `G`.  This gives you your first second order start: `GgAgA`.  Then row 2 and 3 tell you about rows 1-3 in the original table, so you can use them to put together the second row of your second order table: `TgGgA`.  Following this process through, you should be able to build up a second order table without changing the first order code too significantly (and then even higher orders if desired).

Hope that helps!

Edit: **First Order Chains**

To put together the first order chains in the first place, you will probably want to use a few for loops, storing the result in a list, or some more efficient data class (like sets).  For now, I’ll use lists, because they’re easy and clear to use.

For one thing, if you’re working with millions of lines, be careful about each and every thing you store.  Taking care to find the right data structure, and not including any extra information (like the “g” between each character) is essential.  But for now, what would the basic structure look like?

Well, you want to loop over both row and columns, while knowing exactly how far we need to skip to grab info from multiple lines.  To do this, we should begin by figuring out these skipping distances, then going into the two-dimensional for loops.  Here’s a rough sketch of the program:

```
dataString = *given data*
colNames = []
row = 0
col = 0
totalLines = *number of lines*
startChar = *number of characters before first M column*
skipDist = *number of characters between columns*
n = startChar
while (dataString[n] != “\n”):  # get all of the column names
    if dataString[n] == “M” or dataString[n] == “S”:
        colNames += dataString[n:n+2]
lineLength = n
numCols = len(colNames)
mcOrder1 = [[] for i in range(numCols)]

# now loop over the columns, storing the new data as you go
for row in range(totalLines)
    for col in range(numCols):
        currentChar = row*lineLength+startChar+skipDist*col
        nextLineChar = currentChar + lineLength
        mcOrder1[col] += [dataString[currentChar] + dataString[nextLineChar]]
```

While there are definitely some holes in this code, I hope it gives you some instinct for what sort of things you should be doing if you want to write the functions for this yourself, instead of using outside libraries.  Once you have the mcOrder1 list filled, you should also be able to build a reverse version of these loops to turn mcOrder1 into a big string and do it again.  Alternatively, you could break dataString into a list with one helper function, and then process that MUCH more efficiently, and do identical operations on future lists (or whatever data structure you use.

I hope this was helpful--let me know if there’s anything further that’s confusing you or if any of the code was unclear.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Chris: Can you please respond to how to prepare `1st order markov chain`. I had done it using pandas but ran into memory issue while trying to store large markov chains on memory (several million lines). I would rather create a markov chain and write it on file on go. Also, the preparation of 2nd order makes sense to me.

Comment: Let me know if you have chance to give some thoughts on preparation of `first order markov chain`. Thanks

Comment: @everestial007 Yeah I’ll add it on as an edit to my original answer.  Glad to help!

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and will let you know if I have any questions. I have to add more complexities to this problem but that if for later. I will keep in touch if help needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Helper Functions**

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import add as sadd, split as ssplit

def mchain(s, n=1, sep=None):
    s = np.asanyarray(s, dtype=str)
    if sep == None:
        _s = np.append(s, np.tile(s[-1], n))
        s_ = np.append(np.tile(s[0], n), s)
        return sadd(sadd(_s, 'g'), s_)
    else:
        s = np.array(ssplit(s, sep, 1).tolist())
        _s = np.vstack([s, np.tile(s[[-1]], (n, 1))])
        s_ = np.vstack([np.tile(s[[0]], (n, 1)), s])
        _s_ = sadd(sadd(_s, 'g'), s_)
        return sadd(sadd(_s_[:, 0], sep), _s_[:, 1])

def proc(d, n=1):
    ch = {k: mchain(d[k], n) for k in d if k not in ['PG', 'block']}
    ch['PG'] = mchain(d.PG, n, '|')
    ch['block'] = d.name
    return pd.DataFrame(ch).reindex_axis(d.columns, 1)
```

**First Order**

```
df.groupby('block', group_keys=False).apply(proc, n=1)

   block       PG   M1   M2   M3   M4   S1   S2   S3   S4
0     15  AgA|TgT  AgA  AgA  CgC  GgG  TgT  TgT  CgC  TgT
1     15  GgA|CgT  GgA  GgA  GgC  CgG  CgT  CgT  GgC  AgT
2     15  TgG|AgC  TgG  CgG  TgG  TgC  AgC  AgC  CgG  AgA
3     15  TgT|CgA  TgT  TgC  TgT  AgT  CgA  CgA  GgC  CgA
4     15  CgT|GgC  CgT  AgT  CgT  AgA  GgC  GgC  TgG  GgC
5     15  AgC|CgG  AgC  AgA  AgC  CgA  CgG  CgG  GgT  CgG
6     15  GgA|TgC  GgA  CgA  GgA  CgC  TgC  TgC  GgG  TgC
7     15  GgG|TgT  GgG  CgC  GgG  CgC  TgT  TgT  GgG  TgT
0     17  TgT|GgG  TgT  TgT  AgA  TgT  GgG  CgC  GgG  CgC
1     17  GgT|AgG  GgT  GgT  GgA  CgT  AgG  AgC  AgG  CgC
2     17  TgG|CgA  CgG  TgG  TgG  CgC  CgA  CgA  GgA  TgC
3     17  AgT|TgC  AgC  AgT  AgT  CgC  TgC  TgC  TgG  AgT
4     17  AgA|TgT  AgA  AgA  AgA  CgC  TgT  TgT  TgT  AgA
```

**Second Order**

```
df.groupby('block', group_keys=False).apply(proc, n=2)

   block       PG   M1   M2   M3   M4   S1   S2   S3   S4
0     15  AgA|TgT  AgA  AgA  CgC  GgG  TgT  TgT  CgC  TgT
1     15  GgA|CgT  GgA  GgA  GgC  CgG  CgT  CgT  GgC  AgT
2     15  TgA|AgT  TgA  CgA  TgC  TgG  AgT  AgT  CgC  AgT
3     15  TgG|CgC  TgG  TgG  TgG  AgC  CgC  CgC  GgG  CgA
4     15  CgT|GgA  CgT  AgC  CgT  AgT  GgA  GgA  TgC  GgA
5     15  AgT|CgC  AgT  AgT  AgT  CgA  CgC  CgC  GgG  CgC
6     15  GgC|TgG  GgC  CgA  GgC  CgA  TgG  TgG  GgT  TgG
7     15  GgA|TgC  GgA  CgA  GgA  CgC  TgC  TgC  GgG  TgC
8     15  GgG|TgT  GgG  CgC  GgG  CgC  TgT  TgT  GgG  TgT
0     17  TgT|GgG  TgT  TgT  AgA  TgT  GgG  CgC  GgG  CgC
1     17  GgT|AgG  GgT  GgT  GgA  CgT  AgG  AgC  AgG  CgC
2     17  TgT|CgG  CgT  TgT  TgA  CgT  CgG  CgC  GgG  TgC
3     17  AgG|TgA  AgG  AgG  AgG  CgC  TgA  TgA  TgA  AgC
4     17  AgT|TgC  AgC  AgT  AgT  CgC  TgC  TgC  TgG  AgT
5     17  AgA|TgT  AgA  AgA  AgA  CgC  TgT  TgT  TgT  AgA
```

Comment: is always awesome. You gave me a solution to this using pandas which was totally good, but I ran into issues with memory. I am improving my coding skills, but still have problem reading multiple lines and iterating through it. Thanks much again.

Comment: I have to add that closing state transition for both blocks are missing.

Comment: @everestial007 I've updated the code to include the closing state